# Opinion on Glibc getaddrinfo

Tags: java, c, process, glibc, getaddrinfo

`InetAddress.java` is using Glibc function `getaddrinfo()` and according to [CVE-2016-3706](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-3706), 
`getaddrinfo()` is not safe any more.

Does that mean that all the applications which use `InetAddress` class are not safe. What can be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean that all the applications which use InetAddress class are not safe.

Running any application that calls `getaddrinfo` on a system affected by above CVE is unsafe. That includes any Java applications using `InetAddress` as a subset.

> What can be the solution to this problem?

The *only* solution is to update the system GLIBC with a version where above CVE has been fixed.